# Why does the if block get executed after else?

Tags: python, fork

```
import os
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
        print("This is the child")
else:
        print("the child is pid %d" % pid)
```

In the output for the above code, both the if and else blocks get executed. The else first, followed by the if. Is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is effectively unspecified.

As you (probably) know `fork()` copies the current process. In one instance it returns `0`, in the other it returns the pid of the new process.

So both parts are taken, because you're actually executing it twice.

Which one goes first? That depends on which of the two processes the OS chooses to schedule first. Depending on the OS there might be a tendency, or it might always be the same, but you should not depend on that behaviour.